# How to create incremental custom ID in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I create a incremental custom id in mongoDB.

Example:

```
let type = 'x'
let inputCounts = {}
function something(type){
  inputCounts[type] = (inputCounts[type] || 0) + 1;
  return `custom-id-${inputCounts[type]}`
}
something(type)
```

Like this what the above function does, I want something that I can do directly in code for mongoDB
So that I can get a `customID` based on different type, Because like this when I will restart the server the object will get reset.

Thank you

Comment: *I want something that I can do directly in code for mongoDB* ? Do you mean a MongoDB function to do it ? Also do you want it to be incremental for subsequent request ? or can just be random incremental number ? Like 1 is already saved next time it can be anything > 1 (2 or 10 or ...) ?

Comment: Yes mongodb function and it should be sequential based on type I pass

Comment: I don't think there is a function to do that !

Comment: Thank you @whoami, found the solution.

Comment: @Sohan Please share your solution if you have found it, so the community can benefit of. (But I doubt that such function exists for MongoDB)

Comment: Sure @TheeSritabtim

Answer (score 1):

***Thank you for the help mates.

Found the solution so thought will share.***

**Create a counter collection as**

`db.createCollection("counters")`

**or**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Counter = new Schema(
  {
    _id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
    sequence_value: {type: Number}
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
Counter.index({_id: 1}, {unique: true});
var Counter = mongoose.model('Counter', Counter);
module.exports = Counter;
```

**Then create a JS Function :**

```
function getNextSequenceValue(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Counter.findOneAndUpdate({_id: ObjectId(id)}, {$inc: {sequence_value: 1}, upsert: true}).exec(function(
      err,
      counter
    ) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      return resolve(counter.sequence_value);
    });
  });
}
```

**Then you can get the `sequence_value` based on `id` passed.**

`let custom_id = await getNextSequenceValue(id)`
`custom_id will give you the value in sequential order`